# Terminal password

Tags: system-installation, updates

What is the password for OS 4.1 Loki operating system, terminal application ? While attempting to update or upgrade to a newer OS terminal requires a password. How do I locate it ?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same you used to login to your account on eOS. That in mind that your are the administrator of that system.